# window.external.notify passing data other than string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, delegates, function-pointers, window.external

I am trying to write a windows phone app and I want to invoke a delegate when a user wants performs an action. But the problem is the action has to be performed in the webpage and the event has to be handled inside the app. I know this is not a perfect design, but all I am doing is trying to explore ways to modify the data that is being passed from a webbrowser control back to the application.

This is my Question,

```
        +---------------------------------------------+
        | Inside App (C# Code Behind)                 |
        |         App Data.                           |
        |                                             |
        |   Delegate that handles the event.          |
        |      ^       +----------------------+       |
        |      |       |Webbrowser Control    |       |
        |      +       |                      |       |
        |      |       |                      |       |
        |      +------------+Action Performed |       |
        |              |   (HTML Control)             |
        |              |                      |       |
        |              |                      |       |
        |              +----------------------+       |
        |                                             |
        |                                             |
        +---------------------------------------------+
```

I am currently using window.external.notify(somestrings) and using reflection to invoke the method in the code behind. Other than passing around a string can I pass a generic `Object` which when passed to C# code which can later be type cast to a delegate object which can then be invoked?

If not for delegates can I invoke the method that is part of the app in the code behind (C#) by just passing the function's name?

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible to pass a string via  the `Notify()` method.

You could try invoking the method name you are passing via reflection. Alternatively, if you know the methods you may invoke at designtime you could pass a value which you translate in code to the method you're after.

Comment: yeah, you could pass a JSON or XML value to notify() and deserialize it in the code behind.